# vue.js / bootstrap: onclick event method not called, error "Can't find variable: updateDocument"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am new to frontend development, but have basic knoledge of HTML5, CSS and Javascript.

I create a vue.js project and added bootstrap and axios.
My app loads the data from and shows them. But as soon as I click on the button "show","update" or "delete" I get an "Can't find variable: updateDocument" although the method exists.

Please advise me where to look for the error.

[image]

[image]

node version v18.15.0
npm version 9.0.5
vue.js 3
boostrap v5.3

To ensure that the problem is not caused by data - doc.id -, I replaced it by a fixed number.

code snippets from DocumentVault.vue:

```
    <div v-else>
      <ul  v-for="doc in documents" :key="doc.id" >
      <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-header">{{ doc.title}}
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text"> Short Description: {{ doc.shortDescription}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Categorie: {{ doc.categorie }}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Comments: {{ doc.comments }}</p>

          <a class="card-text" v-for="tag in doc.tags" :key="tag.id">
            <div class="badge bg-info" >{{ tag.name }}</div>
          </a>
          <br><br>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button onclick=updateDocument(1)  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Show</button>
            <button onclick=updateDocument(doc.id)  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update</button>
            <button onclick=deleteDocument(doc.id)  type="button"  class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </ul>
       <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <label>
          Title:
          <input v-model="title" type="text" required />
        </label>
        <label>
          Mediatype:
          <input v-model="mediatype" type="text" required />
        </label>
        <label>
          Short Description:
          <input v-model="shortDescription" type="text" required />
        </label>
        <label>
          Categorie:
          <input v-model="categorie" type="text" required />
        </label>
        <label>
          Comments:
          <textarea v-model="comments"></textarea>
        </label>
        <label>
          Tags:
          <input v-model="tags" type="text" />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

```
  mounted() {
    axios.get("/api/documents").then((response) => {
      this.documents = response.data;
      console.info(this.documents)
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.errorMessage = "Failed to retrieve documents.";
      console.error(error);
    });
  },
```

for the method I tried 2 approaches, but the error is the same

variant A)

```
    updateDocument: function (id) {
      axios.post(`/api/documents/${id}`).then(() => {
        this.documents = this.documents.filter((doc) => doc.id === id);
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.errorMessage = "Failed to update document.";
        console.error(error);
      });
    },
```

variant B)

```
    updateDocument(id) {
      axios.post(`/api/documents/${id}`).then(() => {
        this.documents = this.documents.filter((doc) => doc.id === id);
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.errorMessage = "Failed to update document.";
        console.error(error);
      });
    },
```

main.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
```

App.vue

```
import DocumentVault from './components/DocumentVault.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    DocumentVault
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the option API, if so try this:

```
methods: {
    updateDocument() {
      // your code
    }
  },
```

and change your click event to :

```
<button @click="updateDocument">Show</button>
```

Here is link to the vue docs : [Declaring Methods](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-methods)

Comment: Thanks, now the method is found but the request url leads to vue and I rund into a 405. The request should use the URL of my backend.  If I provide for the axios request also the URL of my backend server, I run into a cors problem (Access-Control-Allow-Origin and 405).

Comment: CORS definition was missing in my backend.